# Incorrect Regex Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I found this site:
https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex
and wanted to use for my url validation the regex from the @diegoperini, because according to the table provided on the top of the site, it is the best regex.

When I try to use it, I get a range value error.

P.S. I am using the following Regex expression:

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

and the following online validator:
http://regexr.com/

It does show the error place in the regex, but I don't know how to manage it. I tried to swap the both ranges, but it doesn't do the trick.

I would appreciate some help.

P. P. S.
I use the regex in the AngularJS directive to validate url input.

Comment: What is your regex flavor? (language you are in)

Comment: Javascript, I try to use it in the angularJS directive

Answer (score 1):

Buried within your character classes, you have this range:

```
\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}
```

But it should be:

```
\u00a1-\uffff
```

Your expression `\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}` is not the correct syntax for a hex encoding or a character and as-is means any of "x{}0a1f" plus the range "}-x", but "x" is *less than* "}" so an error is raised to that effect.

Comment: In JS, `\x` requires 2 digit hex code, not 4. `\xffff` matches an `\xff` and 2 `f`s.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for that info. I've changed the proposed fix to `\u`

Comment: Somehow I cannot get none of those regex (from the provided link) running. Probably they are all for php, not for js. I will use the standard angular url verification.

Comment: Is this Regex no correct @Bohemian?                                                         _^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$_iuS

Comment: @siri well that has the change, but it will never match anything due to the first 2 chars being `_^`, which is an impossible case (by definition, nothing comes before start)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$
```